# Cant integrate facebook login in

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am following the android official tutorial to integrate facebook login to my android application, but the application don't start at all and terminate as soon as it is launched. Here is the code of the application.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

Context mcontext;
    /*@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(mcontext);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }*/
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    LoginButton loginButton;
    View view;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
       loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override

            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App codeth
        }

            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                this.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
            } });

    }

    public int onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

        loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
        // If using in a fragment
        // loginButton.setFragment(this);
        // Other app specific specialization

        // Callback registration
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        // App code
                    }
                } );return 0;    } }
```

**Here is the xml file of

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

Comment: did you wrote facebook metadata in manifest??

Comment: yes here is the metadata
 <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

Comment: Here is the logcat, please correct me if I have posted it wrong

02-18 11:55:20.542 1025-2615/? E/BatteryService:  battery updateBatteryLightsLocked mLowBatteryWarningLevel = 15
02-18 11:55:20.552 1025-2615/? E/BatteryService:  level =  47  status = 2
02-18 11:55:20.772 1025-1342/? E/BatteryService:  battery updateBatteryLightsLocked mLowBatteryWarningLevel = 15
02-18 11:55:20.782 1025-1342/? E/BatteryService:  level =  47  status = 2
02-18 11:55:21.182 1025-1342/? E/BatteryService:  battery updateBatteryLightsLocked mLowBatteryWarningLevel = 15

Comment: Have u declared facebook activity in your Menifest.xml like

<activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

Comment: @MahmoodHassan that's not the correct logcat, have you tried what the previous commenters have suggested?